# Querying AWS SQS queue URL using Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-java-2.0

Most operations of the AWS Java SDK for SQS require a queue url.

Given a queue name, the queue url can be queried using the [`GetQueueUrl`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueUrl.html) operation.

Does the `AmazonSQS` client automatically cache the result of this operation, or is it up to the application to cache the queue url to avoid repeated queries?

Comment: Any answer could change with the next release of the AWS SDK.  If you take a look at [the Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sqs) you'll see that releases are very frequent (with 19 releases in September - nearly one per business day).  Is it that hard to hold onto a String in your code?

Comment: @stdunbar I work at a company with a fairly large codebase maintained by many developers, some of them absolute newbies.  I've noticed several places in the code where developers have inlined calls to `AmazonSQS.getQueueUrl()` every time they are performing a queue operation.  At first glance this seems quite inefficient, but perhaps with caching it isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If we look in the [AWS Java SDK code on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-sqs/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSClient.java#L1138), we see that `getQueueUrl()` triggers the usual client preparation hooks (which doesn't appear to include caching), and then immediately jumps to `executeGetQueueUrl()` which makes the request, also without caching. Interestingly, there does appear to be a `URI cachedEndpoint = null;` that doesn't appear to be used anywhere (maybe I'm missing something?).

Taking a step back, this makes sense. Auto-caching the response on the SDK could be dangerous for applications using it, so the decision to cache or not cache is left to the application logic where it belongs. So, if you need to cache the responses, it's up to you to decide how long you want to cache it and where/how to store it.

Comment: Auto-caching at the HTTP level might be reasonable if the server provides appropriate cache control headers.